# How keep background image from repeating in Outlook 2007 and up

Tags: outlook, vml

I'm using VML for a background image in an html email. The background repeats in MSO 12, 14, and 15, despite a "no-repeat" value in the VML object. Code below:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="background-image: url('http://secure.sportssystems.com/eventdata/6389/images/APIInviteBackground.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">
    <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; mso-width-percent:1000; height:775px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;z-index: 1">
             <v:fill type="tile" src="cid:http://.../myimage.jpg" />
    <![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
```

I've also tried using v:background:

```
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; mso-width-percent:1000; height:775px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="cid:http://secure.sportssystems.com/eventdata/6389/images/APIInviteBackground.jpg" />
</v:background>
```

But then I get no background. I'll keep plugging, as I have a feeling the solution is something simple, but would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 16):

Change `<v:fill type="tile"` to `<v:fill type="frame"` and make sure that you have the rect the same size as the td.  Using MSO-width-percent can be glitchy to a degree. As it would only be rendered on the desktop version, you should have no real issues declaring a preset value for this conditional code and I would recommend doing this.

Comment: This worked for me. I had been struggling for hours and the image i had put in the table background was getting stretched horizontally in Outlook for Windows but displaying correctly in Outlook Online. But changing "tile"  to "frame" worked like a magic. Thanks a million

Comment: This solution also worked for me. I owe you a beer!

Comment: Too bad you can't use cover. Only stretch or tile :/

Comment: @Adam: See https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2021/background-properties-in-vml/ and the `aspect="atleast"` and `aspect="atmost"` parts.

Answer (score 5):

By specifying a `size` attribute in the `<v:fill>` element to "100%,100%" I was able to get my image to stretch and not repeat.

Put the following code right after the opening `body` tag:

```
<body>
<div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true">
    <v:fill type="tile" size="100%,100%" src="http://image.mail.minacsmarketing.com/lib/fe9912727d65017d75/m/1/test-bg.jpg"/>
</v:background>
<![endif]-->
    <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr><td>
```

Then close your code with the following code right before the closing `body` tag:

```
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div><!--/end container div-->
</body>
```

Note: your question was for Outlook 2007 and up, for which this works. This solution will not work for Outlook.com emails, as they do not support VML code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It also helped me with dpi related issues when image was looking bigger in VML.